# Should I say where I am from in the first sentence I introduce myself

Tags: professionalism

> Hello, I am XXXX from YYY, I will be working in ZZZ department, nice to meet you ... bla bla bla

This is what I am planing to say in my first introduction to people in my new company.

I will move to the Netherlands and start working in a Dutch firm in November.

My concern is the part where I am from. Maybe it is not necessary, but In my case it can give a sign of confidence, because I am from one of these countries that unfortuately, is famous of terrorism and not having human right.

Help please, this is a very crucial subject to me

#### Update

This question is not duplicated to my previous question, in that one, I am asking how to introduce myself, but in this one I am asking if I should say my origin country. they are obviously different

Comment: Are you a recent transfer from that place, or have you lived here for a while already?

Comment: @Erik I have never lived in the NL, and in November, I will be a new employee in this firm. Is that pleae what you asked about ?

Comment: Yes. Are you moving to the Netherlands and start work in the firm at the same time, or you are working off-site in your own country?

Comment: @Erik moving and **start** working at the same time, **not** working off-site

Comment: Your question is whether you should say which country you are from? You could just leave it out from your public introduction, but if someone asks, tell them with confidence.

Comment: @Pete no , i updated my question to state that it is not duplicate

Comment: Close enough to be a duplicate in my opinion We can't give you precise advice on what to say in every situation; we don't want 100 questions along the lines of "Should I say X" for lots of different values of X.

Comment: Agree with @PhilipKendall. **Less is more user2059935**. You seem to be severely overthinking your new job.

Comment: Netherlands is one of the most open minded countries. You can be open regarding where are you from, but that's not a requirement. If you don't know Dutch you should be transparent about that too.

Comment: _I am asking if I should say my origin country._ -- If you have reservations about mentioning your country of origin (it sounds like you may), then you should just not mention it at first (Hi, I'm XXX. I'm glad to be working in dept YYY, etc.). Someone may ask you though, so be prepared with how you want to answer if you want to avoid disclosing this even when asked.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are new to Dutch society as a whole, it would probably help if you emphasize that you are *just now* here from YYY.

In the bigger cities in the Netherlands, there are lots of foreigners and having an expat join your company won't raise any eyebrows, but if you haven't lived here before it will help to let them know that you just arrived.

The Dutch are, compared to most of the world, extremely blunt, usually very open-minded and they tend to say what's on their mind. You might get a bit of culture-shock and letting them know that you only just arrived to the country might get them to tone it down a bit. (And might get them to offer you a hand in getting familiar with the culture).

I would only do this the first time around. Once you've lived in the Netherlands for a few years, it's likely nobody will care where exactly you're from. And if they do, they'll just ask.

Something like this will get them in the right mindset.

> Hello, I am XXXX. I just arrived here [last week/last month] from YYYY. I will be working in ZZZ department. Nice to meet you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "I am So-and-So from ZZZ and I work for [name your manager/supervisor]. If you need anything that I can help you with, let me know"

You are here in the company to perform your job and you should introduce yourself in that context. Where you are from, who you are married to, what religion you are - all of that is irrelevant to you, your colleagues and your management compared to you being able, willing and ready to perform your duties as a hire.